# Clang Diagnostic Error on file outside CPP project - "Error While processing"

Tags: c++, clang, gtkmm, clang-tidy

Using gtkmm in a cpp project in vscode, everything can build normally even though I have this error.

```
[{
    "resource": "/d:/Dossiers/Repos/Cpp/Motion/src/main.cpp",
    "owner": "clang-tidy",
    "code": "clang-diagnostic-error",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Error while processing",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 2,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 1135,
            "startColumn": 29,
            "endLineNumber": 1135,
            "endColumn": 65,
            "message": "use 'template' keyword to treat 'operator ()' as a dependent template name",
            "resource": "/D:/Programmes/MYSYS64/mingw64/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/adaptors/bind.h"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 21,
            "startColumn": 50,
            "endLineNumber": 21,
            "endColumn": 58,
            "message": "expanded from macro 'SIGC_WORKAROUND_OPERATOR_PARENTHESES'",
            "resource": "/D:/Programmes/MYSYS64/mingw64/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/adaptors/adaptor_trait.h"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 1157,
            "startColumn": 29,
            "endLineNumber": 1157,
            "endColumn": 65,
            "message": "use 'template' keyword to treat 'operator ()' as a dependent template name",
            "resource": "/D:/Programmes/MYSYS64/mingw64/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/adaptors/bind.h"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 21,
            "startColumn": 50,
            "endLineNumber": 21,
            "endColumn": 58,
            "message": "expanded from macro 'SIGC_WORKAROUND_OPERATOR_PARENTHESES'",
            "resource": "/D:/Programmes/MYSYS64/mingw64/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/adaptors/adaptor_trait.h"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 1180,
            "startColumn": 29,
            "endLineNumber": 1180,
            "endColumn": 65,
            "message": "use 'template' keyword to treat 'operator ()' as a dependent template name",
            "resource": "/D:/Programmes/MYSYS64/mingw64/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/adaptors/bind.h"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 21,
            "startColumn": 50,
            "endLineNumber": 21,
            "endColumn": 58,
            "message": "expanded from macro 'SIGC_WORKAROUND_OPERATOR_PARENTHESES'",
            "resource": "/D:/Programmes/MYSYS64/mingw64/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/adaptors/adaptor_trait.h"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 169,
            "startColumn": 36,
            "endLineNumber": 169,
            "endColumn": 72,
            "message": "use 'template' keyword to treat 'operator ()' as a dependent template name",
            "resource": "/D:/Programmes/MYSYS64/mingw64/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/functors/slot.h"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 21,
            "startColumn": 50,
            "endLineNumber": 21,
            "endColumn": 58,
            "message": "expanded from macro 'SIGC_WORKAROUND_OPERATOR_PARENTHESES'",
            "resource": "/D:/Programmes/MYSYS64/mingw64/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/adaptors/adaptor_trait.h"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 205,
            "startColumn": 36,
            "endLineNumber": 205,
            "endColumn": 72,
            "message": "use 'template' keyword to treat 'operator ()' as a dependent template name",
            "resource": "/D:/Programmes/MYSYS64/mingw64/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/functors/slot.h"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 21,
            "startColumn": 50,
            "endLineNumber": 21,
            "endColumn": 58,
            "message": "expanded from macro 'SIGC_WORKAROUND_OPERATOR_PARENTHESES'",
            "resource": "/D:/Programmes/MYSYS64/mingw64/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/adaptors/adaptor_trait.h"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Project is using cmake alongside the Cmake extension in vscode, gtkmm and cpp libraries are used through mingw64

I am not using there files, and I haven't found a way to ignore those files.

Changed exclude paths on vscode, disable clang-diagnostic-errors, didn't work.

Edit:
Undefined `SIGC_MSVC_TEMPLATE_SPECIALIZATION_OPERATOR_OVERLOAD` in sigc++config.h when using gcc, fixed the error.